# Sitefinity Custom Backend Pages MVC

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

I know how to create a backend page through the UI (`../Sitefinity/Administration/BackendPages/Pages`). Is there a way to add one through the project in VS so that I can create a custom MVC Admin Page with control over the controller and styled similar to the rest of the backend?

I would like to add a new section at the top in the backend similar to Dashboard, Pages, Content, Design or Administration which links to one custom MVC page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a good solution to this in combination with Veselin's answer above. Once a page is created through the Sitefinity backend at `../Sitefinity/Administration/BackendPages/Pages` you can add custom MVC widgets. In order to restrict widgets to only appear for the admin pages you can register them to the section 'Dashboard' that is only available for backend pages:

```
[ControllerToolboxItem(Name = "CustomAdminWidget", Title = "Custom Admin Widget", SectionName = "Dashboard", CssClass = "sfMvcIcn")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Best is to create the page through the Sitefinity UI and then just add your MVC widget to the page. Page will look exactly as the other backend pages and you will have control over your widget.

Normally you would create a Group page at top level, e.g. Custom Stuff and then  a standard page underneath.

Comment: So can you limit MVC widgets to be used only on the Admin pages directly from code or even from Sitefinity Advanced Settings? I would not want these custom controllers to be able to be added to regular site pages. From decompiling the `Telerik.Sitefinity.Mvc` dll and looking at  `ControllerToolboxItemAttribute` class it does not seem like that MVC controller decorator has anything restricting where the widget is available.

Comment: Yeah, nothing like that out of the box. I would just put them in a new toolbox section called Backend Widgets or System Widgets or Do Not Touch Widgtets or something like that.

Comment: It seems like I might be able to restrict the permissions on who can see a widget - [sitefinity docs](https://docs.sitefinity.com/tutorial-toolbox-filtering). This would at least prevent non-admins from adding those widgets to pages. I haven't tried it yet, but seems promising.